# Similar functionality to dup2 in boost

Tags: c++, boost, fork, boost-asio, dup2

I would like to do some thing like this

```cpp
acceptSocket = accept(...);
if (fork() == 0) {
  // ..
  dup2(acceptSocket, 1);
  dup2(acceptSocket, 2);
  execvp(/*some command*/);
  
}
```

Now I’m moving to C++ boost and I would like to do the same thing. Is there anything similar to this? Probably it would be Boost Process and socket stream but I couldn’t quite figure out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Boost Process: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/doc/html/boost/process/posix/fd.html

> This property lets you modify file-descriptors other than the standard
> ones (0,1,2).
>
> It provides the functions bind, which implements dup2 and close.

So, example:

```
#include <boost/process.hpp>

namespace bp = boost::process;
using bp::posix::fd;

int main() {
    int acceptSocket /* = accept(...) */;

    bp::child child(
        bp::search_path("someprogram.exe"),
        fd.bind(1, acceptSocket),
        fd.bind(2, acceptSocket));

    child.wait();
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot. Just for anyone coming here later, what I did with a `tcp::socket` instead of `int` is `bp::system(cmd, fd.bind(1, socket.native_handle()), fd.bind(2, socket.native_handle()));`.